# Can I disable Beamer temporarily and continue with Latex as usually?

Tags: beamer, page, missing

Can I disable Beamer temporarily and continue with Latex as usually? Somehow, Beamer messes up my pagenumbers. Many times I get the same page number for consecutive pages. Why is that?

Comment: Each Beamer slide produces a pdf page. Even using a single `frame` you could produce a lot of pages if you use `pause` or items and so on.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](//tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: Also, please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.``

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `handout` option for your documentclass

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
```